# Is there any way to have an action bar without extending AppCompatActivity class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar, listactivity

I'm learning Android and trying to write a simple app that displays a ListView full of texts, so my MainActivity class extends ListActivity to get the setListAdapter method, not AppCompatActivity. Is there any way to show both the action bar and the ListView?

Comment: better to used `ListView` then.....

Comment: You could implement the list as `ListFragment`

Comment: oh God, I blindly followed the instructions on the internet :) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, you should better use a listview component.

But to answer your question you can do this:

add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: that didn't really help me but I just found the answer, thank you man

Comment: @NerdyGuy which answer? You can post it and accept by yourself.